# Nesterov's bound between quadratic and strongly convex cases?

Tags: gradient-descent, convex-optimization, convergence

Are there some examples of simple & strongly convex functions for which the convergence bound of Nesterov’s Accelerated Gradient Method is better than Nesterov’s bound for strongly convex case `(sqrt(1 - 1 / sqrt(k)))` and worse than Nesterov’s quadratic bound `(1 - 1/ sqrt(k))`.

Where, `K = L/m` denotes the condition ratio

Comment: Consider posting in http://math.stackexchange.com/